# IBOutletCollection equivalent in Android?

Tags: android

Is there an Android equivalent for iOS's IBOutletCollection?

If so, how can I implement it?

In iOS I can declare an `IBOutletCollection NSArray *myCollection`, hook up the controls via Interface Builder, but is this same thing possible in Android?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find of doing this is to define a static array with all the view IDs. Like this:

```
private static int[] myViewIds = {R.id.view1, R.id.view2, ...};
```

And then you can easily iterate like this:

```
for (int viewId : myViewIds) {
    View myView = findViewById(viewId);
    // Do stuff with myView
}
```

(Old question, but I was wondering the same thing so thought I'd share...)